# Deploying Qt apps on OS X El Capitan that link against 3rd party library

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator, osx-elcapitan, macdeployqt

I'm trying to deploy a Qt app using El Capitan that used to work on previous version of OS X.

In my .pro file I link against the library:

```
LIBS += -L/Users/rrabien/dev/main/raceman/libxl_mac/lib -lxl
```

When I run macdeployqt I get:

```
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libxl.dylib"
```

I used to copy the dylib to /usr/lib, but I can no longer do that with El Capitan (even using sudo)

Any idea how to get the app to deploy?

Comment: Why can't you copy the dynlib to /usr/lib? Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.5 this explains why El Capitan is rootless: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really